# Why can't I get json data in JS from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to upload a file and get some processed data from it by PHP,but I came across some problems. Here are my simplified codes.

HTML CODE

```
<form action="ajax.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="mypic"> 
<input type="submit" value="upload" id="submit"> 
</form>
```

JS CODE

```
$(function(){
    var button = $('#submit');
    button.click(function(){
        alert("You clicked!");
        getdata();
    });

})
function getdata(){
    function onDataReceived(data) {
        alert("Get the data!");
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax.php",
        method : 'GET',
        cache : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : onDataReceived
    });
}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    $filepath = $_FILES["mypic"]["tmp_name"]；   
    $filename = $_FILES["mypic"]["name"]；

    SOME CODE HRER；

   $mech_para = "Hello";
   $json = json_encode(array("mech_para"=>$mech_para));

   echo $json;
?>
```

Once I clicked the submit button, the page will jump to ajax.php, and it shows {"mech_para":"Hello"}, but without the alert:Get the data!.

But if I delete the first two lines in the ajax.php as below

```
<?php
        SOME CODE HRER；

       $mech_para = "Hello";
       $json = json_encode(array("mech_para"=>$mech_para));

       echo $json;
?>
```

The result turns to be totally fine, the page jump to ajax.php and shows the right data, and the alert(Get the data!) also shows.

I don't know **what causes this result and how to solve it**, I wander **if there is any conflicts between ajax and the GLOBAL VARIABLE _FILE**， OR **if there is any other way that I can both process the file and return the data I want to JS**.
***Very thanks!***

Comment: You're not sending anything at all from the client, yet you seem to be expecting files on the server ?

Comment: I send a file stored in my computer within the form to ajax.php.

Comment: You need to use `POST` in ajax to make `$_FILES` work.

Comment: Nope, the ajax request isn't sending anything, but as you haven't prevented the form from submitting, it could be sending the file and redirecting

Comment: @Yuki, Can you make it more explicit?

Comment: @D.Doe please check the answer from @Marc B everything explained there. What I meant it's that in `$.ajax` function you need to change `method : 'GET',` to `method : 'POST',`

Comment: @adeneo get it,, if the ajax request isn't sending anything, is that means it well not get anythingg? But in my second case, I did get json data, why? and if I am not supposed to use this way to do the whole processing and submtting thing, how can I complement the function?

Comment: @Yuri ok, but I still doesn't works.

Comment: First, you need to change your Response headers (Content type) to JSON (application/json).
In pure PHP you would do: header('Content-Type: application/json');
Second, you need to realize $_FILES is an array, so you need to read it like you would do with an array, you could use foreach or direct index access.

Comment: @Marco, $_FILES is an array, but I can read data from it in the above codes, does it will cause    problems?

Comment: Yes, you need to do some testing before reading ti, PHP will throw notices or warnings depending on your error_reporting, hows yours?

Comment: @Marco, my code throw no error, I've solved it by the codes adeneo provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prevent the form from submitting, and actually send the file.

```
<form id="myForm" action="ajax.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="mypic"> 
    <input type="submit" value="upload" id="submit_button"> 
</form>
```

and then

```
$(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit', getdata);
});

function getdata(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    function onDataReceived(data) {
        alert("Get the data!");
    }

    $.ajax({
        url         : "ajax.php",
        method      : 'POST',
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        data        : new FormData(this),
        dataType    : 'json',
        success     : onDataReceived
    });
}
```

Comment: I still can't the json data back from ajax.php, I don't know what on earth is it....

Comment: So you're not seeing the alert, and no errors in the console (F12), and you changed the ID for the button as in the form above

Comment: I've changed the ID, and still no alert.

Comment: And you added Marc's advice, with the error handler, and there's no errors there either

Comment: Yes, I add a alert function there, no alert neither.

Comment: And you opened the console, in Chrome it would be CTRL-SHIFT-C, and when you refresh the page there's no errors.

Comment: there is always an error : Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined

Comment: That's because it's lowercase, `getdata`, I typed it wrong the first time, but edited it

Comment: lol, another error happened: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: Your version of jQuery is too old

Answer (score 3):

Because you're simply ASSUMING success. You told jQuery to expect JSON, and what you're sending out is almost certainly NOT json.

You're doing a `GET` request, which means it's IMPOSSIBLE for `$_FILES` to contain anything. That means you're generating PHP warnings for undefined indexes

You have no `error` handler on your jquery call, so jquery can't even tell you that it failed to decode this (corrupt) json it received.

Never **EVER** assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. That means you need to have

```
$.ajax(
   ....
   error : function(jqerr, msg) {
      alert('ajax request failed: ' + msg);
   }),
   c....
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll keep this in mind!  But I did't get any error meg neither after adding those codes.